# Popup without background scroll on JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a big JqueryMobile [Popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html) with a semi-transparent brackground color.
Something like:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>SOMETHING BIG</p>
</div>

#popupBasic{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Right now I can scroll inside the popup(because is too big to fit on the screen) **but I don't want scroll in the rest of the page**(which I can see because the background is transparent)

Answer (score 1):

When you activate your popup, set `body { overflow: hidden; }` in your CSS. This will cause the page to freeze, and not allow the user to scroll. Remember to reactivate it when you close your popup though!

Comment: Didn't work, that cause **all** the page to freeze including the popup, and i want scroll inside.

Comment: `body { overflow: hidden; }` only affects the body, it will leave the popup unchanged. Can you please reproduce this problem for me?

Comment: I managed to do in this way.. When the popup is open I set via JQuery position: fixed to the div of the the page and I remove after the popup is closed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours, I suppose that you are calling your popup with ajax, if yes then

a code like this

```
function ajaxFunction(gotid){
$('body').css("overflow","hidden");  // <----- like this 
$.ajax({
.... the rest of your code
```

will help you and to be safe you can set it back by making your close function something like this

```
function closeme(){
$('body').css("overflow","scroll");  // <----- will set it back to scrollable
```